# matching certain digits in a decimal number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I have a column of decimal numbers.

For each row, I want to match other rows and see if each one of the other rows "match".

Two values are considered to have matched IF after ignoring the decimal - the first 4 digits are the same, but rest of the digits are different.

so for example, for a row value of 52.0101:

52.0102 would be a match

52.0101 would NOT be a match

Here is my code so far:

```
cipcode = str(row['CIPCODE']).split('.')[0] + '____'  # Replace decimal with 4 underscores

df['CIPCODE'].str.startswith(cipcode)
```

As you can see, my logic so far only caters to the digits before the decimal, and does not implement the requirement of the digits other than the first 4 being different. I am having trouble figuring out how to proceed, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You want to match only if the truncated string equals `52.01`?

Comment: I want to match if after ignoring the decimal, the first four digits are the same AND the rest of the digits are different. the 52.0101 quoted above is just an example of a row value. I actually have a column containing such decimal numbers called "CIPCODE"

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry for not being clear before

Comment: You could do string matching. Use regexp to get all numbers up to your limit. then match them. You can set up whatever rules you need and then simply match the string as you require. might have issues with scientific notation though. Or you could just floor your values to X decimal places and check equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about to completely ignore the decimal what about something like that

```
target = str(target).replace('.', '')
```

and then

```
lambda x: (str(x).replace('.', '')[:4] = target[:4]) & 
(str(x).replace('.', '')[4:] != target[4:])
```

Comment: this has a weak spot, though your numbers should be at least 4 characters long, otherwise you can define an ordinary function with try-except inside

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but perhaps multiply by 100 and truncate the decimal portion?

Comment: that will take care of matching the first 4 digits, but how to check that rest of the digits are different?